# how to add several patterns to check if one of them is present into a python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I know how to check if a string contain a particular pattern ex :

```
my_list=['hello.1', 'Holla',"Bonjour+","Saloute"]

for i in my_list:
 if '.1' in i:
  print(i)


hello.1
```

but how to add several patterns?  for instance :

```
for i in my_list:
 if '.1' or '+' in i:
  print(i)


hello.1
Bonjour+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` here.

```
liste=['hello.1', 'Holla', 'Bonjour+', 'Saloute']

for word in liste:
    if any(i in word for i in ('.1','+')):
       print(word)
hello.1
Bonjour+
```

Or

You can write

```
if '.1' in word or '+' in word
```

Comment: thank you I will take the last one :)